# What is the [communication] tag for?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have been adding descriptions to tags that had no guidance and I came across one that is particularly vague, or at least extremely broad: [communication](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/communication) is used for only [one question](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/264/13), without making that question significantly easier to find.

Do we want to keep it (if yes, with what definition), or should it be replaced with more specific tags, such as [oral-skills], [writing-skills], etc?

Answer (score 3):

First, thanks for going through our tags!

Now to this specific issue, my 2¢ is that it's not a meaningful tag. Practically every question on a site about language could warrant the [communication](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/communication) tag. I suggest removing it entirely. If the question deserves additional tags, add them, too, but that is probably a separate issue.

Comment: I don't think that specific question needs more tags, so I vote for removing the tag 'communication'.